# Output statistical summary by group for multiple columns based on user input. in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I need to summarize data using Python based on parameters from the user input and output summarized file. The actual data have several columns and groups and user should be able to configure what summary statistics (mean,median, max,min, quartiles) he/she wants to request for any column and group he/she chooses to summarize. The user input can be a JSON file (my_json_param). Here is a toy example of what I am trying to achieve. Compute summary statistics (mean,median) of columns (Height, Weight) by group (HighSchool). I need iterate through my_json_param with multiple combination of parameters and generate one summary file (df_sum) and a separate mapping file (sum_map). Basically, it should be a python function that can take in df and my_json_param and outputs df_sum.csv and a mapping file for summary statistics (sum_map.csv) (headers in sum_map.csv are combination of the column name and summary statistics -for example sum1 is meanHeight).

```
   import pandas as pd
   import json
   # Generate toy data to demonstrate
   df = pd.DataFrame({'HighSchool': ['HS1', 
   'HS2', 'HS3','HS1', 'HS2', 'HS3','HS1', 
   'HS2', 'HS3','HS1', 'HS2', 'HS3'],
'Height':[5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9,5.4,6,6.1],
'Weight':[110,120,130,140,150,160,180,190,120,135,155,185] })
df

# The summary is based on user input. User should be able to input columns names, HighSchool names and summary statistics in a JSON file like this
my_json_param = json.dumps({'Biometric':["Height","Weight"] , 'HighSchoolName':["HS1","HS2","HS3"],'Summarymeasure':["mean","median"]})
my_json_param

#  Output should look like this
df_sum = pd.DataFrame({'HighSchool': ['HS1', 'HS2', 'HS3'],
'sum1': [5.400,5.625,5.725],
'sum2': [141.25,153.75,148.75],
'sum3': [5.40,5.65,5.75],
'sum4': [137.5,152.5,145.0],
                      })
df_sum.style.hide_index()

HighSchool  sum1          sum2             sum3            sum4
HS1         5.400000      141.250000    5.400000    137.500000
HS2         5.625000      153.750000    5.650000    152.500000
HS3         5.725000      148.750000    5.750000    145.000000

# Output mapping file that should look like this
sum_map=pd.DataFrame({ 'sum1': ['meanHeight'],
'sum2': ['meanweight'],
'sum3': ['medianHeight'],
'sum4':['medianWeight'],
                      })
sum_map.style.hide_index()
sum1        sum2        sum3            sum4
meanHeight  meanweight  medianHeight    medianWeight


# I know how to do a summary measure separately in python.
df.mean=df.groupby(['HighSchool'])['Height','Weight'].mean()
df.mean
# I need help in reading JSON file with multiple combination of parameters and generate one summary file and a separate mapping file.
def createsummary (dataframe,jsonfile,outputfile,mappingfile)
....
```

Comment: I feel like there's too much context and it's not entirely clear for me what the question is

Comment: I tried to generate a toy example of what I need to do. Let me know what is not clear.

Comment: Hi, could you show what the final result should look like?

Comment: Added the output check comments "#  Output should look like this" and "# Output mapping file that should look like this".